# typo3 remove duplicated og:tags

Tags: typo3, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

till now I used to add dynamic Titles to the HeaderData:

```
$this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData('<meta name="og:title" content="' .$annonce->geraAdvertTitle() .'"/>');
```

After installing the jh_opengraphprotocol extension I have double og:title's

```
<meta name="og:title" content="detail">//default title
<meta name="og:title" content="Entwickler IBM InfoSphere DataStage (m/w)">//dynamic title
```

Only LinkedIn take the first false title and show "detail"!!
I've tried javascript but it removes it after loading the side!
How can I remove the first meta Tag (server-side solution) only for a specific site??

Thanks for helping me out here

Answer (score 0):

You need a logic with a condition, which does not add the first entries.

As meta-tags could be used multiple times there is no logic which prevents double setting the same tag.

There are plans to optimize it as there also are tags which should not occur twice. but that will be available earlist in TYPO3 9.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to change the behavior of the extension `jh_opengraphprotocol`, either the lines where the array `$og` is filled with the title just can  be deactivated or some settings for the extension can be included where for each attribut can be chosen if it shall be included or not.

The best way is to discuss the latter option with the developer of the extension by posting the request on [github](https://github.com/jonathanheilmann/ext-jh_opengraphprotocol/issues), so further versions would always include the changes.
Also the option to alter some og-properties by user-functions and configuration could be discussed with the author.

The **quick but not recommended way** is just to deactivate these lines: https://github.com/jonathanheilmann/ext-jh_opengraphprotocol/blob/master/Classes/Service/OgRendererService.php#L91-L93 by adding `//` in the beginning of each line.

`$og['title'] = htmlspecialchars(!empty($GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['tx_jhopengraphprotocol_ogtitle']) ?
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['tx_jhopengraphprotocol_ogtitle'] :
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['title']);`

This issue has been filed here: https://github.com/jonathanheilmann/ext-jh_opengraphprotocol/issues/64
Feel free to comment there and add further explanations and ideas there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I deactivate the lines it will be affecting all the pages right? I will the og:title be removed only on one page and when the content is what is given on the plugin tab (ex. title=detail), the other title name will be filled dynamicaly from my own extention.

Comment: You could reverse the logic in the line:
```$og['title'] = htmlspecialchars(!empty($GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['title']) ?
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['title'] :
            $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['tx_jhopengraphprotocol_ogtitle']);```

Comment: You should add then the requirement for a condition in the filed issue on github too.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot